# how show graph with relationship filtrered?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship

I have a node called "COG1476" which has different relationships with other nodes but I would like to get only those relationships that have a score> = 700 and I would also like to get the graph.

```
MATCH (cog1 {name: 'COG1497'})-[rel:coexpression|cooccurence|database|experimental|fusion|neighborhood|score|textmining]->(cog2)
WHERE toInteger(rel.score)>=700, toInteger(rel.cooccurence)>=700, toInteger(rel.coexpression)>=700, toInteger(rel.database)>=700, toInteger(rel.experimental)>=700, toInteger(rel.fusion)>=700, toInteger(rel.neighborhood)>=700,toInteger(rel.textmining)>=700
RETURN cog1, cog2, rel.score>=700, rel.cooccurence>=700, rel.coexpression>=700, rel.fusion>=700, rel.database=700, rel.experimental>=700, rel.neighborhood>=700, rel.textmining>=700
```

---

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input ',': expected 0..9, '.', 'e', 'E', an identifier character, whitespace, node labels, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', '~', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, FROM GRAPH, CONSTRUCT, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE UNIQUE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, CALL, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 2, column 32 (offset: 160))
"WHERE toInteger(rel.score)>=700, toInteger(rel.cooccurence)>=700, toInteger(rel.coexpression)>=700, toInteger(rel.database)>=700, toInteger(rel.experimental)>=700, toInteger(rel.fusion)>=700, toInteger(rel.neighborhood)>=700,toInteger(rel.textmining)>=700"
                            ^
```

Comment: The specific syntax error you're getting is because you've got commas separating the terms in your `WHERE` clause instead of `AND`s or `OR`s. 

However, you need to add more information to properly answer the question - does each relationship type in your `MATCH` clause have a `score` property? Your question suggests so, but your query doesn't. Also what output do you expect? If you just want the graph you can return cog1, cog2 and rel and skip all the other bits.

Comment: yes, each relationship has a numerical property considered a score in integer numbers. I would like to have the graph that shows only those relationships with scores greater than or equal to 700.

Comment: And each 'score' property has a different name? Like the 'score' property on a COOCCURRENCE relationship is called 'cooccurrence'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I think two things are wrong:

- You've got a syntax error in your `WHERE` clause, which we fix by replacing the commas with `OR`s
- You need to configure the Neo4j Browser app to only show matched relationships (or use the Table view)

First let's fix the query:

```
MATCH (cog1 {name: 'COG1497'})-[rel:coexpression|cooccurence|database|experimental|fusion|neighborhood|score|textmining]->(cog2)
WHERE toInteger(rel.score)>=700 OR toInteger(rel.cooccurence)>=700 OR toInteger(rel.coexpression)>=700 OR toInteger(rel.database)>=700 OR toInteger(rel.experimental)>=700 OR toInteger(rel.fusion)>=700 OR toInteger(rel.neighborhood)>=700 OR toInteger(rel.textmining)>=700
RETURN cog1, cog2, rel
```

That should return data and not blow up with an error. However, in the Browser you'll still see all the relationships between the nodes even though some of those relationships don't match our `WHERE` clause - that's just the default behaviour of the Neo4j Browser when visualising a graph.

To fix that, hit the Settings cog icon at the bottom left of the screen and untick the checkbox marked 'Connect result nodes' at the end of the configuration options. You'll now only see connections between nodes that you've explicitly selected - you may want to toggle this back on after you're done.

[image: Showing the location of the Connect result nodes setting in Neo4j Browser]

You can also check your results by using the Table view, which will show only those relationships that matched the criteria in your WHERE clause.